# How to redirect to other page on a button click event using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to redirect to a new page on a button click. I need to write this using jquery. I don't know how to write the code for that.
Here is my HTML

```
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
   <a class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%" id='approve'>Approve</a>
</div>
```

and the script i wrote is

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            //LIVEICON
            $('#approve').on('click',function(){
                var comment = $('#comments').val();
                if(($('#comments').val()!="")){                             
                    alert(comment);
                    $('#successalert').html('<strong>Approved...!</strong>').show().fadeOut(5000); 

                    }
                else{

                    if($("#comments").val()==""){$('#comments').css({'background-color':'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.09)','border-color':'red'});$('#comments_er').css('display','block');}
                    if($("#approver").val()==null){$('#approver').css({'background-color':'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.09)','border-color':'red'});$('#approver_er').css('display','block');}
                }
            });
        });
        $('#comments').change(function(){
            if ($('#comments').val()!="") {$('#comments').css({'background-color':'#fff','border-color':'#ccc'});$('#comments_er').css('display','none')}
            if ($('#comments').val()=="") {$('#comments').css({'background-color':'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.09)','border-color':'red'});$('#comments_er').css('display','block')}

        });
        $('#approver').change(function(){
            if ($('#approver option:selected').val()!=null) {$('#approver').css({'background-color':'#fff','border-color':'#ccc'});$('#approver_er').css('display','none')}
            if ($('#approver option:selected').val()==null) {$('#approver').css({'background-color':'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.09)','border-color':'red'});$('#approver_er').css('display','block')}

        });
```

What is the issue with this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: @JoshWhitlow  Hi john.. You see the code now.. Its not duplicate. I am having a different issue

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple javascript with in jquery click event.

here is how your code will look like.

```
$('#link').click(function(){
  alert("Clicked");
  window.location.href="http://smashingmagazine.com";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using simple `HTML`? You could make it dynamic with echo in `PHP`.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="yourlink"><input type="submit"></form>
```

To open a new tab:

```
<form action="yourlink" target="_blank"><input type="submit"></form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='yourlink';">
```

**Your code within jQuery:**

jQuery:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
  alert("Clicked");
  window.location.href="yourlink";
});
```

Html:

```
<button id="link" >Link</button>
```

Some **information** about onclick function: [w3schools onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use jQuery? Can you not just:

```
<a href="mypage.html"><button>Button Text</button></a>
```

Comment: Actually i need to do some validations. After finishing that validations only my page need to redirect. That's why i am using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the button `onclick="location.href='pageurl.html';"`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
$('#link').click(function(){
  alert("Clicked");
  document.location.href = 'http://smashingmagazine.com'
});
```